# GML and C/C++ language question

Tags: c++, c, game-maker

Is GML (Game Maker Language) script is clipped in C/C++ language, and GML wrote the code to Visual Studio C++, it will always be correct, because it is just under C++ language features?

I think that a bit wrong to have written that question could be to ask yet another generation of weeks. But if correct, is not need to ask again.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking if GML is a subset of C++?

Answer (score 5):

GML is a distinct language developed for Game Maker. It bears some similarity to C and C++ on the surface, in terms of its syntax (keywords, grammar and structure), but it is otherwise unrelated to C++ -- it certainly is not a sub- or super-set of the C or C++ languages. GML differs from C(++) in a lot of ways... for example it does not require variable declaration, has a much simpler memory allocation model, and several additional extra language constructs (such as the "with" block).

You could write your GML code within Visual Studio, but it wouldn't work well. You might get syntax hilighting, but VS could not compile GML in general and using Game Maker itself to author GML is a far better idea since the tool and the language are tightly integrated.